# ERROR force:data:tree:import CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY entity type cannot be inserted

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, error, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

My issue is whenever I am trying to sfdx import user records to another org I get this error:

```
ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  {"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"referenceId":"ProfileRef1","errors":[{"statusCode":"CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY","message":"entity type cannot be inserted: Profile","fields":[]}]}]}
```

And I want to add that I have updated dataImportApi.js file with proper `const` and I have added a Permission Set to my user `Create and Update Second-Generation Packages = true`

But I still struggle with this issue. I have browsed everywhere for same errors but cannot find a solution for it.

I am importing three objects: 1 Profile, 1 UserRole and several (not a lot, less than 50) user records. Is it possible to import users with prepopulated UserRole and Profile? 
FYI, Profile and UserRole on that org already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

force:data:tree:import always creates new records. You can't insert Profile objects. As such, that won't work. You can import such records, but not with this tool. You'll need to use force:data:bulk:upsert. Note that you won't be able to fully automate this anyways (using **only** dx), because usernames still need to be unique in each org. You need a script to generate random user names.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer!